# Override MVC form submit in js, but then override that

Tags: javascript, dom, jquery-events

I have a view that has a delete button on it that makes a form in each row of the table:

```
<td>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "FP/WorkItem",
            new { fId = Model.FPId, workId = @w.FId })) {
        <input name="deleteWorkItem" type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-default" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');" />
    }
</td>
```

That works all well and good but I don't want the crummy alert dialog. I want to use a nice thing like bootbox. So I modify this to remove the onclick on the button and I add some JavaScript:

```
$("input[name='deleteWorkItem']").click(function (e) {
    //return confirm('Delete selected item?');
    e.preventDefault();
    bootbox.confirm("Delete selected item?", function (result) {
        return result;
    });
});
```

Without the `preventDefault` the confirm box never appears. With the `preventDefault` the form doesn't post back if the user decides to not delete.

How can I have both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep the `e.preventDefault()` and in confirm function callback manually trigger form submission:

```
bootbox.confirm("Delete selected item?", function (result) {
    $(this).closest("form").submit()
    return result;
}.bind(this));
```

Comment: when i go with the js solution i remove the onclick event in the html button

Comment: this does prevent the form from being submitted and it does allow the form to be submitted but not the correct form. I should have included that <td> tag in my original post. There is a form for each row in the table. but this method submits a form that results in just a postback basically

Answer (score 0):

You've to preventDefault the form instead of button.
See an example:

```
 $("form").on("submit", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); //prevent default form submit

        //do the work here
    });


$("#buttonToSubmit).on("click", function(){
     //Line used to force submit the form
     $("form").off("submit").submit();
});
```

Comment: but once i prevent default on the form submit and the user says that yes they would like to delete the record i have no way to then submit the form because it was prevented already

Comment: I've edited my response. Take a look and see if it'll help you.

Comment: this does allow the form to submit but its not the form that i need. its not the delete form that the Html helper method creates.

Comment: You can change the jQuery selector to the Id of your form. Another option is to create the form on the fly.

Comment: i will never know the id of the form. it is generated in each table row by mvc